# use bcrypt() in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, validation, bcrypt

this code is written in validation.js to validate the all laravel change password forms dynamically

```
$.validator.addMethod("matchp", function(value, element)
{

 var dbpass = $("#old").val();  
// #old value is fetch from database in type=hidden in frontend and its in bcrypt format.



var txtpass = bcrypt($("#oldpass").val());  
// #oldpass value is fetch from frontend its user value and it sholud convert in bcrypt format.  

// So that we can compare it to verify the old password while changing the old password.


    // Check for equality with the password inputs
    if (dbpass != txtpass ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}, "Your Passwords Must Match");
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Its not working as i am using bcrypt() in jquerry validation file

Comment: You shouldn't be exposing password hashes to the client.

Answer (score 0):

[Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) function means an algorithm which gives different hash everytime for a unique string with some different salt. So it is not possible to validate it by using any JS Validation Plugin. Of course, you can check different input field values without using any hashing technique, like in the same way when validating password and confirm password fields.

*If you are really required to use bcrypt at client-side, use a static salt.*

**Updated,** if you are using @Nevins-b [JavaScript Bcrypt](https://github.com/nevins-b/javascript-bcrypt) plugin then you can do it by using same salt to validate different fields.

Hope this is satisfactory to your question.

Comment: It means as i can use bcrypt() in php  but i cant use it in jquery or .js file. @Rohan

Comment: Use https://github.com/nevins-b/javascript-bcrypt and validate multiple fields  by using same salt.

Comment: I found similar question regarding the same on StackExchage https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93395/how-to-do-client-side-hashing-of-password-using-bcrypt

Comment: You can use validation `remote:` to check bcrypt from server side also.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because Laravel passwords are also salted.

What I would do is

- Pass #oldpass un-encrypted to your back-end using ajax
- On your back end compare the #oldpass with the current password using `Hash::check`

  `if(Hash::check($request->oldpass, Auth::user()->password)){
        return true;

   }else{
        return false;
   }`

Dont forget to add the facades to the top of your Laravel controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Comment: But I want dynamic validation so while entering user know that its wrong password

Comment: use the on 'blur' or 'keyup' events to trigger the ajax call. 

`$("#oldpass").on('blur',function(){
 
 //ajax call here

})`

Comment: nikhil, sorry, but you really shouldn't want to do that. This could only work if you (a) send the correct hash to the client, where it is prey to brute force attacks, or (b) you need to check the password against the server after each keystroke, which generates too much false password checks. For security, login should be disabled after a few false tries. Or at least suspended for some time (increasing after every wrong try), again to block brute force attacks. Compare this to the unlock mechanism of your cellphone.